# How to make videos play more than 2x faster

Tags: video, script, html, javascript, youtube

Youtube has an option for playing videos 2x faster than usual, which I find extremely helpful for learning about various topics. But sometimes even then the video is moving too slow for my liking and I really would like to learn the content at a more natural pace. I was wondering how to increase the pace of playing from say 2 to 3,5 etc...

Is there some way I could script a solution to do this?

Comment: Just curious--how much coffee must be consumed for triple or greater speed to seem natural?  :-)

Comment: lmaoo...on one end a lot, on another end not too much! i think it has more to do with videos where the presenters say a lot of fluff per unit of actual material that i'm interested in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for Google Chrome at least was a plugin by the name of "Video Speed Controller"